# Apache log no longer works

Tags: 12.10, apache2

I saw that my  /var/log/apache2/error.log  log was getting very big (runs a long time when I cat file, or open in editor). So I deleted it with rm. Not only does it not work now, it doesn't work when I recreate the file and chmod 777. How do I reenable it?

I tried restarting apache, it gives this error:

```
$ service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                      /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is still writing into the deleted file which isn't really deleted until Apache is stopped.

To restart Apache you need to be `root`:

```
sudo service apache restart
```